# Objective C variables in Async block does not change the Class variable value

Tags: objective-c, json, xcode, block, dispatch

I try to use my parsed JSON values from async block in other methods and viewDidLoad but, it returns the value inside the block, but in other methods it just return null

here is my Viewcontroler.m file code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

 @interface ViewController ()

@end

NSString *buttonText;

@implementation ViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

 [self URLconnection];

  NSLog(@"this is value: %@", buttonText);

  }



  - (void)URLconnection {



NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@“XXXXXXXXXX"]];

NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [[self getURLSession] 
 dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^( NSData *data, 
 NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error )
                              {
            dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                    ^{
                // parse returned JSON array
                NSError *jsonError;
    NSArray *parsedJSONArray = [NSJSONSerialization 
  JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 
   error:&jsonError];


        NSLog( @"%@", [parsedJSONArray valueForKey:@"data" ] );
                        NSDictionary *dictionary = [parsedJSONArray 
      valueForKey:@"data"];

                        NSLog(@"this is dictionary %@", 
  dictionary[@"buttonText"]);

                        buttonText = dictionary[@"buttonText"];



                                    } );
                }];

[task resume];
 }

@end
```

in the code above the NSLOG in the block return value but NSLOG in the viewDidLoad return null

Comment: You don't need dispatch to main to parse json.

Answer (score 0):

Because the code in the block is executed asynchronously, it means when you are trying to print the value in the `viewDidLoad()` it has no value, so it is printing Null, which is right. When Block ends it's process and get's the data from the server, it will have the value in your variable and that prints the correct response.

Hope it clears.

Comment: I understand what you mean, so how should I do it now ?

Comment: You are doing it right, just set the buttonText value to your actual button's title when you get the response from the server and mean time, show an activityIndicator to user to indicate some process in on it's way.